# Tex Capacity Exceeded with csname and recursion

Tags: errors, counters, compilation-error, csname

I would like to try to do some input with relative paths (like in the import package but I would like to write it)

When I compile I have a Tex Capacity exceeded. Could you maybe help me with this problem ?

My project structure/code on overleaf is [here](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5def205352d9730001163227).

Thank you, and sorry for my english.

Edit :

This is the main code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\title{import}
\author{mathias.cabiochdelalande }
\date{December 2019}

\newcounter{recursion}
\newcounter{minusrecursion}
\setcounter{recursion}{0}
\setcounter{minusrecursion}{-1}

\newcommand{\importdebug}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\import}{O{.} m}{%
    \setcounter{recursion}{0}%
    \setcounter{minusrecursion}{-1}%
%
    \expandafter\def\csname Handler\arabic{recursion}\endcsname{#1}%
%
    \typeout{import #2 -> path(\therecursion:\theminusrecursion) : \csuse{Handler\arabic{recursion}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\importdebug}{0}}{%
        \input{\csuse{Handler\arabic{recursion}}/#2}%
    }{%
        \input{#2}%
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\subimport}{O{.} m}{%
    \typeout{subimport #2 -> path(\therecursion:\theminusrecursion) : \csuse{Handler\arabic{recursion}}}%
    \stepcounter{recursion}%
    \stepcounter{minusrecursion}%
    \typeout{subimport before #2 -> path(\therecursion:\theminusrecursion) : \csuse{Handler\arabic{minusrecursion}}}%
%
    \expandafter\def\csname Handler\arabic{recursion}\endcsname{\csuse{Handler\arabic{minusrecursion}}/#1}%
%
    \typeout{subimport #2 -> path(\therecursion:\theminusrecursion) : \csuse{Handler\arabic{recursion}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\importdebug}{0}}{%
        \input{\csuse{Handler\arabic{recursion}}/#2}%
    }{%
        \input{#2}%
    }%
%
    \addtocounter{recursion}{-1}%
    \addtocounter{minusrecursion}{-1}%
}

\begin{document}

    \ifthenelse{\equal{\importdebug}{0}}{%
        \import[other]{other}
    }{%
        \import[other]{other/other}
    }
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\importdebug}{0}}{%
        \import[dira]{other}
    }{%
        \import[dira]{dira/other}
    }

%   \bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

The code in other/other.tex, dira/dirb/dirc/other.tex, dira/dirb/dird/other.tex

```
\section{a simple section}
```

The code in dira/other.tex

```
\section{dira}

    \subimport[dirb]{dira/dirb/other}

    \subimport[dirc]{dira/dirc/other}
```

The code in dira/dirb/other.tex

```
\section{dirb}

    \subimport[dird]{dira/dirb/dird/other}
```

Comment: Okay, I've edited my post.

Comment: can you give a top level specification of what this is trying to do, it seems vastly over complicated for what I think is the intention so I suspect my guess of the intention is wrong.

Comment: I join @DavidCarlisle, please make your example **Minimal** so that it is easier for us to help you. By the way, why do you use `\makeatletter`? Why do you use `\endinput`?

Comment: I used an online example for makeatletter but maybe it's useless. For the endinput, I put it in every included files but, with your question, I saw that it's useless. I can reduice a bit the example but it's the minimum to test the error.